# vim - set filetype in autocmd FileType

Tags: vim, hook, autocmd

I'd like to change filetype in `autocmd FileType` hook. Thre reason is that I'd like to use NeoMutt syntax file for `.muttrc` instead of Vim's default syntax file. I've installed NeoMutt's syntax files with Plug manager:

```
Plug 'neomutt/neomutt.vim'
```

And I've it in runtime path (I can set it with `set ft=neomuttrc`). But when I open `~/.muttrc`, Vim still uses default syntax file (`set ft?` prints `muttrc`). I've tried the following:

```
autocmd FileType muttrc setl filetype=neomuttrc<CR>
```

but the `filetype` is still set to `muttrc` after I open `~/.muttrc`. How can I change the `filetype` in `autocmd FileType` hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<CR>` should be removed:

```
autocmd FileType muttrc setl filetype=neomuttrc
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and this worked for me:

```
autocmd FileType muttrc set filetype=neomuttrc
```

I would recommend [wrapping this up in a `augroup` and clearing the group](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html).

```
augroup neomuttrc
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType muttrc set filetype=neomuttrc
augroup END
```